# Diagonalize the simultaneous matrices and its background

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request

For two $n \times n$ nonnegative definite Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ over the real number field $\mathbb R$:

> **Question1:Is there always a
>   nonsingular matrix $P$ over the same
>   field $F$ which makes $P^{H}AP$ and
>   $P^{H}BP$ both diagonal?**

If the answer is yes, in which part of the matrix theory(or L.A.) can I find such results?
If the answer is no, whether there's a similar result or some counterexample?

> **Question2:What special property does this kind of $P$ have?**

Will it still be Hermitian or have some rank inequality in relation with the $rank(A)$ and $rank(B)$, like this sort.

> **Question3:What is its corresponding background in Abstract algebra?**

For example, the Jordan decomposition correspond to the primary decomposition, like this sort.

Moreover I want to know if this result has any application?

Most probably in Lie algebra, because this proposition is taken from some Lie algebra course.

Comment: I'm very curious, how such a question was raised and left unanswered during a Lie-algebra course...

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as stated, since "nonnegative definite" and "Hermitian" aren't defined for a general field.  (Even if your field is the complex numbers, do you want to assume $A$ and $B$ commute, so you can take $P$ to be unitary?)  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118680/ for information about which fields have the property that every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-negative definite" matrix over a general field? What does "Hermitian" mean over a general field? What "special property" do you have in mind. (See if you can identify such property in the case when $F={\mathbb R}$.) 

Comment: Update and made corrections about the conditions, real field will be just fine. My ignorance, sorry.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization ?

Comment: As far as I understand your question (which make little sense even after corrections: e.g. what is $F$ now?), it is basic material which you will find in any book treating these questions. Voting to close.

Comment: It's not so obvious as it seems, Gatnmacher provided a proof using row operations in *Theory of matrices* and A.Horn proceed as a special example of nonnegative matrices. Yes, I shall have done more before asking que1 and que2. But as far as I concerned I did not see why this is related to lie-algebra. Thank all your kind suggestions! It really helps.

Comment: To all those voted to hold this topic: I have no idea what is the meaning/beneficial of putting such an old post on hold. And it is actually one of the first posts that attracts me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested to look at Section 20 on Simultaneous diagonalization of a pair of Hermitian forms of the following book:

> **Prasolov, V. V.
>   [Problems and theorems in linear algebra.](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf) 
>   Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 134. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1994.**

Among other things the following results are proved:
(diagonalizable is in the sense of hermitian).

Consider $n\times n$ hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$.

(1) If $A$ is a positive definite then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

(2) If $A$ is invertible then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if $A^{-1}B$ is diagonalizable and all its eigenvalues are real.

(3) If $A$ and $B$ are both nonpositive or nonnegative then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. (It seems that, this is the result you are looking for).

(4) If $A$ and $B$ are not simultaneously isotropic then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.