# Can one deduce the fundamental theorem of algebra from real calculus and linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, teaching

**Motivation**: let $A\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric. Then by the method of Lagrange multipliers, a maximum of $x\mapsto x^tAx$ on the compact unit sphere $\mathbf{S}^{n-1}$ must be an eigenvector of $A$. In particular, we have that

($\star$) $\det(tI-A)$ has a real root if $A$ is a real symmetric matrix.

Now this is trivial using the fundamental theorem of algebra (which we did not) and also seems pretty strong. Thus:

Is there a simple way to deduce the fundamental theorem of algebra from ($\star$)?

<sub>(Note: I [asked this on the *Mathematics* Stack Exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396725/can-one-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-using-that-symmetric-real-matri) and did not get an answer.)</sub>

Comment: Derksen gave a proof using linear algebra and characteristic polynomials. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647746 or https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/fundthmalg/fundthmalglinear.pdf.

Comment: Try proving this way that $x^2+1$ has a root.

Comment: Derksen's paper is here: https://sites.lsa.umich.edu/hderksen/wp-content/uploads/sites/614/2018/05/A.I.a.15.pdf. Of course necessary preliminaries are that one can take square-roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and that every odd-degree polynomial has a root.

Comment: @markvs the idea I had in mind, like in the Galois theory proof, is to also use that every polynomial of degree 2 has a complex root (and if needed that any odd degree real polynomial has a root)

Comment: You want an "easy" proof? There are very easy elementary proofs without using linear algebra. Take any of these proofs and add some linear algebra to it.

Comment: @markvs I don't want an "easy" proof, just wondering if we can somehow extend the argument I gave to nonsymmetric matrices (with complex eigenvalues). of course we can prove FTA in many other ways...

Comment: Yes, you used the word "simple", not "easy" ("is there a simple way to deduce the fundamental theorem of algebra from (⋆) ). Start with your argument, add a prove of FTA, and you are done.

Comment: @markvs $x^2+1$ has a root just by construction, namely $i$. But whatever you have in mind, the following fact is an easy exercise: let $K$ be a field of char $\neq 2$ in which $K^*/{K^*}^2$ has order 2 (e.g., the reals). Then for every quadratic extension $L$ of $K$, every element of $K$ has a root in $L$.

Comment: Could you change that to Ask how one might deduce the fundamental theorem of algebra, with no details?

Comment: Although not exactly in the spirit of the question, the proof of the FTOC using the fundamental group of the punctured plane is "essentially" just linear algebra and calculus.  But not of the sort tomm appears to be enquiring about.

Comment: Given the above result about symmetric matrices and the (related) statement that every positive number has a square root, one can prove that any [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator) $N$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is diagonalisable. The problem then becomes, given a field extension $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$, to prove that there *exists* an inner product on $F$ (considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$) such that elements of $F$ operate as normal operators (commute with their transpose).

Comment: The only way I could see find such an inner product uses "averaging" over elements of norm 1 in $F$. That is an *additional* statement requiring a proof using analysis over $\mathbb{R}^n$ over and above the statement that bounded functions on compact statements have a maximum.

Answer (score 30):

I don't think so. Indeed the result that every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable is true for some orderable non-real-closed field $K$ (see [this answer by Will Sawin](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118683/14094) to [Over which fields are symmetric matrices diagonalizable ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118680/over-which-fields-are-symmetric-matrices-diagonalizable) ). Hence you can't deduce that every nonconstant polynomial over $K[i]$ has a root, since it's false.

---

NB: about the terminology: orderable means that it admits a total ordering for which the set of positive elements is closed under addition and multiplication.

A real-closed field can be defined as an orderable field $K$ such that the field $K[i]$ is algebraically closed. Here $K[i]$ means the analogue of obtaining complex numbers from real numbers, starting from $K$ instead, namely $K^2$ with elements written as $x+iy$ with multiplication $(x+iy)(x'+iy')=(xx'-yy')+i(xy'+x'y)$. This is a field because $-1$ is not a square in $K$. Of course with basic background in elementary commutative algebra this is the same as $K[t]/(t^2+1)$.

Comment: Moreover, Will's answer could be adapted to apply to the field $K:=\bigcup_k \mathbb{R}((x^{1/2^k}))$. Then $K[i]$ is closed under square root, but still not algebraically closed. So we can't do it even using diagonalizability and the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ has square roots.

Answer (score 1):

(Expansion of my comment above.) This does not answer the diagonalisability of *all* matrices. It just extends it from symmetric to normal.

Assume that we have an ordered field $R$ for which one can prove that (a) any symmetric matrix over $R$ is diagonalisable and (b) that every positive number in $R$ has a square root. Here is a proof that any matrix $N$ such that $N$ and $N^{t}$ commute is diagonalisable.

1. If $H$ is a skew-symmetric matrix with entries in $R$ then $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & H \\ -H & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric and thus diagonalisable. This means that there is a basis $x_i,y_i,z_j$ and numbers $a_i$ in $R$ such that $Hx_i=a_iy_i$, $Hy_i=-a_ix_i$, $Hz_j=0$, for some sequence of indices $i$ and $j$.
2. If $K$ is a orthogonal matrix with entries in $R$ such that neither of $\pm 1$ is an eigenvalue, then $H=(K+1)(K-1)^{-1}$ is an invertible skew-symmetric matrix. Applying the above, one can show that $K$ is diagonalisable over $R[\sqrt{-1}]$.
3. If $K$ is *any* orthogonal matrix with entries in $R$, then $K$ is diagonalisable over $R[\sqrt{-1}]$. (Apply the above to the perpendicular of the eigenspaces for $\pm 1$.)
4. Given a normal matrix $N$ (meaning $N$ commutes with $N^t$), we write $N^{t}N=P^2$ where $P$ is positive definite symmetric by using diagonalisation and the existence of square-roots of positive elements. It follows that $K=NP^{-1}$ is orthogonal *and* $K$ commutes with $P$. Since $K$ and $P$ are diagonalisable (over $R[\sqrt{-1}]$ and commute, so is $N=KP$.